# Why "a is b" false even though both have same values?

Tags: python-3.x

```
a=10+5j
b=10+5j
print(a is b)
#Both are of complex types
```

Here a and b are assigned with two same complex numbers then why "a is b" command showing its false in tha place of true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have different memory addresses.

```py
>>> a = 10 + 5j
>>> b = 10 + 5j
>>> a is b
False
>>> a == b
True
>>> a = b
>>> a is b
True
```

Comment: If we assign a and b with value 10, then "a is b" is true. Whats the difference

Comment: 10 is a primitive, 10 + 5j is a class (of type complex)